# How do I display recent News on silverstripe frontpage

Tags: php, date, silverstripe

I am using the silverstripe/simple_news module from Arno Poot for my SilverStripe 3.5.3 CMS.

The news module works perfectly and news is saved and displayed normally. I am just not happy with the way it displays on the page.

I would like to put a news brief div on the front page with the last 10 news articles. But I have little documentation to go by. How would I get the last 10 news articles.

I also would like to create a sidebar on the news holder page listing the entire news archive in order / group links by:

```
--------------- 
| Year        |      Page Content listing of this month only  
|   Month     | 
|     Date    |  
| Year        | 
|  Month      |  
|    Date     | 
--------------
```

...etc. (pub date as dd-MM-yyyy)

I think the operation should be similar but since I am somewhat new at customizing SilverStripe, I have many questions yet.

Answer (score 5):

Great question. Syndication of content is a really fundamental pattern in SilverStripe development, or really any content management system. A guiding principle of SilverStripe is that it would much rather empower you create exactly what you want by writing some code than give you 80% of what you want in some turnkey, out-of-the-box solution.

There's a lot written about this already. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/tutorials/extending_a_basic_site/#showing-the-latest-news-on-the-homepage.

What you'll want to do is create a method in your home page controller that returns a list of articles to your home page template.

```
public function RecentNews()
{
  return NewsArticle::get()->limit(5); // sort is already handled by default_sort
}
```

Then on the template:

```
<% loop $RecentNews %>
$Title / $Date / etc..
<% end_loop %>
```

Your second question about grouping them by year is a bit trickier. I did a tutorial on this a while back. Check out https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/beyond-the-orm-building-custom-sql?ref=hub

Needless to say, update all of those class names and field names to reflect the module you're using, e.g. ArticlePage -> NewsPage.

Comment: Grouping by year should be quite simple with `GroupedList`, see: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.0/howto/grouping-dataobjectsets/

Comment: You might also be able to get the DataList directly in the template by using `<% loop List('NewsArticle').Limit(5) %>`, but it feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: UncleCheese I have watched your video tutorials with interest. Thank you for your comments.

The article from your docs is almost there but it si based on an earlier version of the SS CMS. It would be very interesting to see your version of what could be done in another video tutorial.

Comment: I should also mention the news module mentioned has a NewHolderPage which treats news articles as database items. Another item of concern.

Comment: Success! I did get the desired result. Thanks Uncle Cheese for your hints. The resulting code sing bootstrap theme appears as :
    <div><span style="font-family: 'Open Serif',serif; font-size: 1.6em;">
      <strong>2017</strong></span> <!-- $Date.Year -->
    </div>
    <% loop $RecentNews %>
        <div class="calendar_day">
         <div class="month">$Date.ShortMonth</div>
         <div class="day">$Date.DayOfMonth</div>
        </div>
        <div class="front-news">
         &nbsp;<a class="links" href="$Link" >$Title</a>
        </div>
        <hr /><% end_loop %>

Comment: With some effort, I have been able to add the top 7 news articles to the front page using methods extracted from the tutorials.

However, the tutorials promise a future tutorial on grouped lists that has not been posted.

I think the reference given by bummzack is close but I have no idea what to group in the project. The Archive Dates only returns a list of dates. That is good to build the list of archives for the sidebar, but it is not grouped by year, only by month with year displayed.

Comment: I should say the ArchiveDates list is ordered by year/month/monthnum.  Any ideas on how to get a list of articles from the link of year/month item in the list?